# $(X,\tau_X)$ is a path connected, then is there a continuous function from $(X,\tau_X)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\tau_E)$ with , $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

I think the answer to this question is yes there exists. My main reasoning is that since there is a continuous path $\gamma: ([0,1],\tau_E)\rightarrow (X,\tau_X)$, with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$ I can consider $\gamma^{-1}$ but I don't know how to prove that this would be continuous, and I end up doubting myself.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Or maybe  another way to tackle this problem would be considering a path $\gamma: x\rightarrow y$ in $X$, a path $\psi:0\rightarrow 1$ in $[0,1]$, then for any $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$, consider $f\circ \gamma=\psi$ would this imply that we can find $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 2):

You will need some extra hypotheses:
Suppose $X$ has the trivial topology. Then it is automatically path connected and every continuous map $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ must be constant.

Comment: Well we know that $x,y$ are distinct points in $X$ would this be sufficient?

Comment: and a priori it is a general question that it is valid for any path connected topology on X

Comment: Of course you can take $x$ and $y$ to be distinct points in some space with trivial topology. My answer just points out that the answer to your general question is "no". For instance your statement implies that $X$ is a Hausdorff space...